# MySQL - Prevent code duplication within CTEs

Tags: mysql, sql, common-table-expression

I hope someone can give me some tips to improve the following query. There is an application that sends messages to and receives messages from a server and are stored in an interval to DB. The goal is now to make some aggregate stats for these rates, i.e., the peak for incoming and outgoing messages, and normal rate for incoming and outgoing messages.

I know I can do it with using a CTE, but given it only needs one new variable per CTE part there is a lot of reused code, which I really hope can be better done.

```
WITH

daily_peak_in_stat as (
    select day,
           engine,
           min(interval_start) as interval_start_peak_in,
           max(interval_end)   as interval_end_peak_in,
           max_peak_incoming_msgrate
    from (select day,
                 engine,
                 interval_start,
                 interval_end,
                 peak_incoming_msgrate,
                 max(peak_incoming_msgrate) over (partition by day, engine) as max_peak_incoming_msgrate
          from daily_running_rates) t
    where peak_incoming_msgrate = max_peak_incoming_msgrate
    group by day, engine, max_peak_incoming_msgrate
),

daily_peak_out_stat as (
    select day,
           engine,
           min(interval_start) as interval_start_peak_out,
           max(interval_end)   as interval_end_peak_out,
           max_peak_outgoing_msgrate
    from (select day,
                 engine,
                 interval_start,
                 interval_end,
                 peak_outgoing_msgrate,
                 max(peak_outgoing_msgrate) over (partition by day, engine) as max_peak_outgoing_msgrate
          from daily_running_rates) t
    where peak_outgoing_msgrate = max_peak_outgoing_msgrate
    group by day, engine, max_peak_outgoing_msgrate
),

then the other parts to finally do a select * from all and do a join to get the final result
```

Since I also have the in and out base rates, there will be like almost 4 duplicated blocks in the query, where I mostly need to change peak_incoming_rate to peak_outgoing_rate to base_incoming_rate etc..

Does anyone can provide some tips to improve the query? I know CTEs cannot function like a JAVA function where I pass in the parameter and it returns me the fields, but there should be sth to not make this such a long duplicate query.

The result schema would look like this for example:

```
| day | engine | interval_start_peak_in | interval_end_peak_in | peak_msgrate_in | interval_start_peak_out | interval_end_peak_out | peak_msgrate_out | etc. etc
```

Many thanks!

Comment: Use your where criteria as a conditonal case expression.

Comment: Thanks for your response @Stu.. How would that look like with my example? thanks

Comment: You can have a single CTE that returns both rows, using `WHERE peak_incoming_msgrate = max_peak_incoming_msgrate OR peak_outgoing_msgrate = max_peak_outgoing_msgrate`

Comment: thanks for the response @Barmar, I was looking at that as well, but got stuck with the interval_start and interval_end (time) columns, since those need to be included in the result (See the final schema), and these column values change based on the type of rate (peak_in, peak_out) etc

Comment: `MIN(IF(peak_incoming_msgrate = max_peak_incoming_msgrate, interval_start, NULL)) AS interval_start_peak_in`

Comment: You have subqueries in the CTE datasources - convert them to one more CTE which selects all columns mentioned...